# Retrieving links from a Google search using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, search, beautifulsoup, tweepy

I'm building a Twitter bot using Tweepy and BeautifulSoup4. I'd like to save in a list the results of a request but my script isn't working anymore (but it was working days ago). I've been looking at it and I don't understand. Here is my function:

```py
import requests
import tweepy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import os
from tweepy import StreamListener
from TwitterEngine import TwitterEngine
from ConfigEngine import TwitterAPIConfig
import urllib.request
import emoji
import random

# desktop user-agent
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
# mobile user-agent
MOBILE_USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-G930V Build/NRD90M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.125 Mobile Safari/537.36"




# Récupération des liens
def parseLinks(url):
    headers = {"user-agent": USER_AGENT}
    resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    if resp.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "html.parser")
        results = []
        for g in soup.find_all('div', class_='r'):
            anchors = g.find_all('a')
            if anchors:
                link = anchors[0]['href']
                results.append(link)
        return results
```

The "url" parameter is 100% correct in the rest of the code. As an output, I get a "None". To be more precise, the execution stops right after line "results = []" (so it doesn't enter into the for).

Any idea?
Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Google changed the HTML markup on the page. Try to change the search from `class="r"` to `class="rc"`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"

def parseLinks(url):
    headers = {"user-agent": USER_AGENT}
    resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    if resp.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "html.parser")
        results = []
        for g in soup.find_all('div', class_='rc'): # <-- change 'r' to 'rc'
            anchors = g.find_all('a')
            if anchors:
                link = anchors[0]['href']
                results.append(link)
        return results

url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=tree'
print(parseLinks(url))
```

Prints:

```
['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree', 'https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree', 'https://www.britannica.com/plant/tree', 'https://www.treepeople.org/tree-benefits', 'https://books.google.sk/books?id=yNGrqIaaYvgC&pg=PA20&lpg=PA20&dq=tree&source=bl&ots=_TP8PqSDlT&sig=ACfU3U16j9xRJgr31RraX0HlQZ0ryv9rcA&hl=sk&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjOq8fXyKjsAhXhAWMBHToMDw4Q6AEwG3oECAcQAg', 'https://teamtrees.org/', 'https://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/trees-woods-and-wildlife/british-trees/a-z-of-british-trees/', 'https://artsandculture.google.com/entity/tree/m07j7r?categoryId=other']
```